# How to install libwebp in alpine Linux Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I want to install libwebp dependency for my docker image. How can I download and install libwebp using docker file? One method is you can download libwebp and ADD files to image as follow.

```
ADD resources/vts/libwebp-0.4.1-linux-x86-64  /lib/libwebp-0.4.1-linux-x86-64
```

But I need to install it by running a command like this.

```
RUN apk upgrade -U \ && apk add ca-certificates ffmpeg \ && rm -rf/var/cache/*
```

How can I achieve that? I refer the following image to create my docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand you right way, but you can install `libwebp` and  `libwebp-tools` packages as other packages described in your question.

The final `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade -U && \
    apk add ca-certificates ffmpeg libwebp libwebp-tools && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/*
```

Now you can find `dwebp` binary file by the following path:

```
/ # which dwebp
/usr/bin/dwebp
```

EDIT:

If you want to install another `libwebp` version on alpine platform you need to add package repository from the previous alpine versions and define version of package you need to install.

For your particular case there are the following versions of `libwebp` package in alpine package repositories:

```
0.4.4-r0 - alpine v3.3
0.5.0-r0 - alpine v3.4
0.5.2-r0 - alpine v3.5
0.6.0-r0 - alpine v3.6
0.6.0-r1 - alpine v3.7
```

For example you want to install `libwebp` version `0.4.4-r0`. The `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade -U && \
    apk add ca-certificates ffmpeg && rm -rf /var/cache/*

RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.3/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk add --no-cache libwebp=0.4.4-r0 libwebp-tools=0.4.4-r0
```

Comment: where i can find the dwebp file ?

Comment: @NuwanChamara I've edited the answer with the info you need.

Comment: can we manage version of libwebp? i mean, how i can we specify the version ? Is there a way to download a specific version?

Comment: @NuwanChamara I've added information about versions management.